# Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 not working

Tags: server

I have tried a clean install of ubuntu server 16.04.1 10 times now and it still doesn't work. Installation process is normal but when it's done and I plug out installation media(usb) and it restarts it just goes black screen and there a blinking white line like I am typing. I tried everythiny, only thing I can do is restart using Ctrl+Alt+Del. Please help me I wasted 48h on this problem. I have Intel Celenor dual core 2.4Ghz CPU, Intel Graphics and HP motherboard in PC HP 110. I am installing on 2x8gb usbs(in raid, no hdd) and I am using 2x4gb for swap area.

Comment: Forgot to mention I was just reinstalling the OS and earlier it worked, same version(16.04) and it worked but I was using 2x8gb usbs. One is like HDD and one is swap.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god. I disabled legacy boot devices and turned on uefi devices and it said no boot disks whatevs but then I restarted set off uefi off and legacy on and changed raid usbs to be firstly on boot and now it works. :D